# How to properly write multiple functions depending on one another in a python class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am currently learning python Classes and I trying to wrap my head on how to use them efficiently. I am creating a Class that initializes a path to a CSV file and has two functions that do the following:

1. **load_data**
2. **ProcessTimeColumn** which takes the loaded df and infer the column that could be turned into a datetime, convert it and add it as an index.

My challenge is how can I use the return from the *load_data* function to use in the *processTimeColumn* function.
My challenge is when I try to run it as below;

```
data= prep_data("./datasets/AirPassengers.csv")
data= data.load_data()
df= data.processTimeColumn()
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'processTimeColumn'
```

Below is my code snippet and some of my trial and errors. Appreciate some guidance;

```
class prep_data():

    def __init__(self, path):
        
        assert path.split(".")[-1] == "csv", "Your file should be in CSV format"
        self.path= path

    def load_data(self):
        """load_data loads target data and returns a df

        Args:
            path (str): path of the file (CSV)
        """
        self.df= pd.read_csv(self.path)
        return self.df

    def processTimeColumn(self, column_index= None):
        """processTimeColumn takes the date column in string format and turns it into a datetime format and sets it as the index

        If no column_index argument is passed, it tries to infer which column can be transformed into a datetime format

        Args:
            column_index (int, optional): column indexer of user identified datetime column. Defaults to None.
        """
        if column_index == None:
            #looping through the columns and trying to convert them to datetime and setting the datetime column as index
            for column in self.df.columns:
                if self.df[column].dtype == "object":
                    try:
                        self.df[column]= pd.to_datetime(self.df[column])
                        self.df.set_index(column, inplace= True)
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
        else:
            self.df.iloc[:, column_index]= pd.to_datetime(self.df.iloc[:, column_index], format= "%Y-%m")
            self.df.index= self.df.iloc[:, column_index] 
            self.df.drop(columns= self.df.columns[column_index], axis= 1, inplace= True)
        return self.df
```

I have tried to create 'self.df =None' variable to try to refer to it as a class variable.

```
def __init__(self, path):
        
        assert path.split(".")[-1] == "csv", "Your file should be in CSV format"
        self.path= path
        self.df= None
```

I have tried to use df instead of self.df as below but still giving the same error;

```
def load_data(self):
    """load_data loads target data and returns a df

    Args:
        path (str): path of the file (CSV)
    """
    df= pd.read_csv(self.path)
    return df

def processTimeColumn(self, column_index= None):
    """processTimeColumn takes the date column in string format and turns it into a datetime format and sets it as the index

    If no column_index argument is passed, it tries to infer which column can be transformed into a datetime format

    Args:
        column_index (int, optional): column indexer of user identified datetime column. Defaults to None.
    """
    if column_index == None:
        #looping through the columns and trying to convert them to datetime and setting the datetime column as index
        for column in df.columns:
            if df[column].dtype == "object":
                try:
                    df[column]= pd.to_datetime(df[column])
                    df.set_index(column, inplace= True)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
    else:
        df.iloc[:, column_index]= pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, column_index], format= "%Y-%m")
        df.index= df.iloc[:, column_index] 
        df.drop(columns= df.columns[column_index], axis= 1, inplace= True)
    return df
```

I would appreciate any guidance on classes or ways to improve my coding.
Thank you.

Comment: Here `data = data.load_data()`, `load_data()` returns a `DataFrame`. any subsequent operations on `data` will be on the `DataFrame`.

Comment: As a guideline in any OOP language, and with few exceptions, a function that has a side effect (`load_data` modifies your object internal state) should NOT return anything. Conversely, a function that returns something (such as `processTimeColumn`) should NOT have side effects. This is sometimes reffered to a as [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). think what is the responsibility of this class, the name `prep_data` is very weak and would likely invite you to a poor design.

Comment: As an aside, if the statement is simply `data.load_data()` it will work the way you intend it. `return self.df` isn't needed since `self.df` is now an attribute (`data.df`) of your `data` object.

Comment: Thank you @istepaniuk for your clarification. so to make sure I get you right load_data shouldn't return anything and probably neither should processTimeColumn, right? should I be using the self.df as an attribute? and if so, do I need to initialize it in the __init__ function?

Comment: @Axe319 ok that is clear for me now. for  functions that changes the nature of the object, no need for the return. how to have that object accept the second function, that would run on a df? what would the function arguments be? (self.df?)

Comment: You could simply place `self.load_data()` in `processTimeColumn` if it's always going to be the same loader method.

Comment: Without seeing the whole picture, it's difficult to understand what is the purpose of this code. Avoid symbols like "df", "pd", and meaningless ones like "data", "value", etc. I can only guess that the "index" that you find is important for the missing query operation in this class, perhaps -that- missing method should be the only one that you client code (main ?) invokes. The other methods should probably not be exposed to the ouside of your class (you declare them with an undescore, such as `def _processTimeColumn(...`

Comment: @Axe319 yeah I get your point. I am just using this as an example to learn OOP and classes. so I am wondering what would be a good way to create optional functions that can be run on an isntance. example you can load the dataframe from path and have the option to parse dates or do other functions instead.

Comment: @istepaniuk noted on the generic variable names. can you please clarify on the part of not exposing the functions to the outside and and add a leading "_" ? what would be the purpose of that?

Comment: @MoutazGendia Python exposes all of an objects attributes to the caller. So when `data` is an instance of the `prep_data` class. you can directly access the attribute `self.path` with `data.path`, even change it to something else like this `data.path = None`. Maybe you don't want the caller to ever worry about `self.path`. To do this you would just rename it to `self._path`. This lets the person that instantiates the class know that they probably shouldn't access that attribute because you intend it to be private.

Comment: @istepaniuk While those are good points on `data` and `value`, I don't think anyone who has seen `pandas` being used would not know what `pd` and `df` stood for.

Comment: @Axe319 Thank you so much for explaining it. I understand better now. appreciate it :)